# Tradingview Pine script - set min stop loss

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to set a minimum value for a stop loss currently based on setting the stop loss on moving averages, but if the stop loss is less than X I would like to set the minimum value.

So currently if the price is below ma1 it weill set the stop loss at ma2, but if the price is below ma2 it will set the stop loss at ma3. What should I add to set the minimum value at e.g. 0.6 % ?

I am just learning pine script so I have just tried a couple of things that didn´t compile. Halp?

```
if buy[1]
    en := open
    sl := en > ma3[1] ? ma4[1] : ma4[1]
    tg := en + profit_mult * abs(en - sl)
    trl := en + trail_mult * abs(en - sl)
    trl_perc := (trl-en)/en
    buy_indx := bar_index
    buy_str = "Reward: " + tostring(round( ((tg-en)/en)*100 , 2)) + "%, " + tostring(round( tg - en, 2)) + "\nRisk: " + tostring(risk(sl, en, "buy")) + "%, " + tostring(round(en-sl, 2))
    label.new(bar_index, tg, yloc=yloc.price, text=buy_str, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_none, size=size.small)
    strategy.exit("BUY_EXIT", "BUY", limit=tg, stop=sl, comment="B-Ex", alert_message=ExitLong)
```

Comment: 0.6% of what? What is `en`? Your code checks if `en` is above `ma2` and not `ma1`.

Comment: sorry for my noob post, i realise that my ability is lesser than my ambition...  
 `en` is open price. 
So I want to check if the difference between open price and ma4 is less than 0.6 % then set the the stop loss at a minimum value of 0.6 %. Does that make sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
minSL = close - (close * 0.006)

if buy[1]
    sl = ((en - ma4) / en) < 0.006 ? minSL : na
    //checks if the difference between open and ma4 is less than 0.6%, sets sl at 0.6% below close if true
```

**Edit:** *Combined with your previous sl conditions*

```
sl := ((en - ma4) / en) < 0.006 and not en > ma3[1] ? minSL : en > ma3[1] ? ma4[1] : ma4[1]
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand where I went wrong in my previous thinking now, but I a getting an error: 

Cannot call 'operator >' with 'expr1'=series[bool]. The argument should be of type: float

Comment: You can remove the `not` from this expression: `and not en > ma3[1] ?` and replace `>` with `<`. Should look like this `sl := ((en - ma4) / en) < 0.006 and en < ma3[1] ? minSL : en > ma3[1] ? ma4[1] : ma4[1]`

Comment: Fantastisc, it now works as intended with the small amendment of `en` should be `> ma3[1]` - Thanks a million!